# Codeigniter - Call to member function on non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Could somebody please explain to me why I am receiving the below error, I have received it many times before and have not found out why:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function category_exists() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\application\controllers\news.php on line 50
```

**The controller (news.php):**

```
...

    public function category($category,$id,$title){


        if($this->news_model->category_exists($category) == true){
            echo 'true';
        }
        else {
            echo 'false';
        }

}
...

The model:

        function category_exists($category)
{
    $this->db->where('news_category',$category);
    $query = $this->db->get('news_category');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you could explain what the error means and why it is a non-object or how to turn it into an object that would be great....

**EDIT: MODEL IS AUTOLOADED**

Comment: I may be off, but aren't model names case sensitive? So if your model is `class News_model` it should be called by `$this->News_model->category_exists`. (though you have omitted the declaration, so this is only a guess)

Comment: @danneth usually you call it lowercase, and use Uppercase in class naming. It's a CI convention, it takes care of that by itself

Comment: Write that as an answer. You were 100% correct. Nice one.

Comment: @DamienPirsy oh.. though it is uppercase in the docs `$this->load->model('Model_name');

$this->Model_name->function();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied to answer:

I may be off, but aren't model names case sensitive? So if your model is class News_model it should be called by $this->News_model->category_exists. (though you have omitted the declaration, so this is only a guess)

Comment: I've worked a lot with CI and I'm pretty sure I never had this issue so far...Who knows!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it `config/autoload.php`?

If yes then load it in the `config/autoload.php` file (In the bottom)

`$autoload['model'] = array();`

If not,load it:

```
$this->load->model('news_model');
```

The model file name must be the same as the model class name.

Check constructor with user guide too.

```
function __construct() { // Call the Model constructor parent::__construct(); }
```